# No display options in AMD Catalyst Center

Tags: catalyst

I want to configure my double monitor system - laptop + external monitor. 
I used to have the same configuration using my previous laptop (just bought a new laptop).
So I installed proprietary linux AMD driver downloaded from the official website. Everything works fine, I got a huge fps increase after installing. But I cannot configure my second monitor in AMD Catalyst Control center, there is no such options (but I always did in that way). I can do so using System Setting->Display, but after every reboot I should do it again.
An I am just wondering why there are no such options anymore, what has been changed?

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: I have the same drivers installed on my laptop and there is no option to configure screens either. This is using version 13.1 I presume?

Comment: 13.2 as well :(

Comment: What is it you're trying to configure exactly?

Comment: The same settings that you can find now in System Settings->Display (I mean the relative location of displays, etc.) are used to be in AMD Control Center. 
I am wondering weather they just completely removed this section (Display Section) from Control Center or it can be obtained somehow?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to obtain them. If you're having to reset these settings (in the system settings) after you reboot then I'd probably post a separate question about that. Using the system settings option is the better and simpler option as its not driver dependent and won't be lost when you update the driver. I've never found the need to reset these options after rebooting. It may be a bug that you need report and not another question, you can find info on bug reporting [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs)

Comment: I agree the idea of keeping display settings separate and not depending on the driver is very good. But yes, my problem is about resetting the settings after every reboot. Thanks.

Comment: I think I got the answer on this question, I cannot post the answer, cause have a low reputation. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

So here is the answer on my question.

There is no more display settings in AMD Control Center. Now all display settings are in System Setting->Display, which make sense, cause all displays settings are kept separate of the driver - they are driver-independent.

The problem with resetting display settings after every reboot does not connected to the absence of display settings in AMD Control Center and seems a bug, that should be posted on launchpad.com